# PHP table confusion

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Firstly I'm very new to PHP, I'm trying trial and error method to get my stuff to work.

Ok basically here is how the following code looks like, please check it out first before you read my question:

[image: http://oi47.tinypic.com/2m4515l.jpg]

I'm trying to remove the entire Registered Users table and instead where it says 'Nickname' I'd like to HYPERLINK all those names like I did to the registered users, but since I'm going to use a HTML code inside a PHP, it wouldn't allow me to do that so, so I'm very confused in how abouts I'm going to get this to work... In otherwords I just want to add  in the table column 'Nickname' and also use the firstname method to know which user's nick I've clicked on. Hope you can help me because I am really confused at this point

```
echo "<table width='1000' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='5' border='2' align='left'>";  // starting from here



 echo "<tr>


    <td><center><b>RANK</td></center></b><td><b><center>Nickname</td></center></b><td><center><b>Kills</td></center></b><td><center><b>Deaths</td></center></b><td><center><b>Hits</td></center></b><td><center><b>Damage</td></center></b></tr>";
$i = 0;
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 $i++;
 echo "<tr> 
     <td><center><b>".$i."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Name']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Kills']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Deaths']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Hits']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b><font color='#FF0000'>".$info['Damage']."</font></td></center></b></tr>"; 
 } 
 echo "</table>";

 $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pProfile") 
 or die("Can't connect (TABLE ERROR 2) : ".mysql_error());


 echo "<table width='270' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='5' border='2' >";

 echo "<tr><td><b><center>.Registered Users.</td></center></b></tr>";
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) 
 { 
 $i++;

    ?> 
 <tr><td><b><center><a href="usersProfile.php?firstname=<?= $info['Name'] ?>"><font color="#CCFF00"><?= $info['Name'] ?></font></a></td></center></font></b></tr>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your aprox 8th line, which is this:

```
<td><center><b>".$i."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Name']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Kills']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Deaths']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Hits']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b><font color='#FF0000'>".$info['Damage']."</font></td></center></b></tr>";
```

for this one:

```
<td><center><b>".$i."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b><a href=\"usersProfile.php?firstname=".$info['Name']."\"><font color=\"#CCFF00\">".$info['Name']."</font></a></td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Kills']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Deaths']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b>".$info['Hits']."</td></center></b>"."<td><center><b><font color='#FF0000'>".$info['Damage']."</font></td></center></b></tr>";
```

also as you want to remove the 'registered users' table remember to remove all code including and below this line:

```
$data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pProfile")
```

Of course I have to say that PHP code is very poorly written :-(

Comment: Thats very helpful of you, it did fix, and yeah PHP is very poorlly written :D